# Metric Spaces, Distances to Sets, and Inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, metric-spaces

$\textbf{Question}$

Let $C$ be a nonempty subset of a metric space $(\mathcal{X}, d).$ Show that
$$ (\forall x \in \mathcal{X})(\forall y \in \mathcal{X}) ~~ d^{2}_{C}(y) \leq 2 d^{2}(x,y) + 2 d^{2}_{C}(x), $$
where
$$ d_{C} : \mathcal{X} \rightarrow [0,+\infty] : x \mapsto \underset{z \in C}{\inf} \, d(x,z) $$
(observe that if $C = \varnothing,$ then $(\forall x \in \mathcal{X}) ~~ d_{C}(x) = +\infty$).

$\textbf{Solution}$

Here is an attempt:

Take $x$ and $y$ in $\mathcal{X}.$ By the triangle inequality,
$$ (\forall z \in \mathcal{X}) ~~ d(y,z) \leq d(y,x) + d(x,z). $$
Taking the infimum over $z \in C$ and appealing to the symmetry of the metric $d$ yields
$$ d_{C}(y) \leq d(x,y) + d_{C}(x). $$
Taking the square of both sides, we have
$$ d^{2}_{C}(y) \leq d^{2}(x,y) + d^{2}_{C}(x) + 2d(x,y)d_{C}(x).  $$
Observe that
$$ d^{2}(x,y) + d^{2}_{C}(x) + 2d(x,y)d_{C}(x) = 2 d^{2}(x,y) - d^{2}(x,y) + 2 d^{2}_{C}(x) - d^{2}_{C}(x) + 2d(x,y)d_{C}(x). $$
Hence,
$$ d^{2}_{C}(y) \leq 2 d^{2}(x,y) + 2 d^{2}_{C}(x) + [ - d^{2}(x,y) + 2d(x,y)d_{C}(x) - d^{2}_{C}(x) ]. $$
Equivalently,
$$ d^{2}_{C}(y) \leq 2 d^{2}(x,y) + 2 d^{2}_{C}(x) - [ d(x,y) - d_{C}(x) ]^{2}, $$
and thus
$$d^{2}_{C}(y) \leq 2 d^{2}(x,y) + 2 d^{2}_{C}(x),$$
since $[ d(x,y) - d_{C}(x) ]^{2} \geq 0.$ Therefore, the result follows. Q. E. D.

Comment: The conclusion from $d_{C}(y) \leq d(x,y) + d_{C}(x)$ to $d^{2}_{C}(y) \leq 2 d^{2}(x,y) + 2 d^{2}_{C}(x)$ is equivalent to the inequality between arithmetic and geometric mean.

Answer (score 1):

This logic is fine. I would suggest adding a couple more words about infimising over $z \in C$: something like, "Define $z:=\mathrm{arg}\min_{w \in C} d(x,w)$, then $d_C(y)\le d(y,z)$, so...". I would also combine your third-last and second-last equations, introducing them with "Rearranging, we obtain".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll make sure to incorporate that in my future write-ups. Only one question: by implicitly writing $z \triangleq \textrm{argmin}_{w \in C} d(x, w),$ don't we assume that the set of minimizers has cardinality 1? I would assume that we cannot make this supposition in general.